# How to not escape characters in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, html-escape-characters

I have a blog model. I have text field where I want to write in HTML, for example including an `a` tag. The permission class used on unsafe methods is `isAdminUser`. I don't necessarily have to escape the characters. Is there way where I could **not** **escape** the characters.

Comment: you want to store html code in the database right? are you using django templates or the REST api to display the data/content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bit of code helped. I basically had to override to_representation.

```
def to_representation(self, instance):
    ret = super().to_representation(instance)
    ret['text'] = html.unescape(ret['text']) 
    return ret
```